# Problem with ditaa and foreign characters in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using emacs for mac os X and org-mode. I was trying to create a diagram with ditaa with the following code:

```
#+begin_ditaa skipting.png -e utf8 -r
                +----------------+
                | Bestun         |
                | á staðsetningu |
                | hleðslustaura  |
                | c707           |
                +----------------+
#+end_ditaa
```

The output is not what I expected, i.e. the letters á and ð do not show up properly, is there a way to fix this?

Fix: Use the chosen answer below but remember to add ditaa to your babel languages in the .emacs file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you have a current version of org-mode, you should use the babel syntax:

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file skipting.png :cmdline -e utf-8 -r -v
...
#+end_src
```

With respect to UTF-8 encoding, I've made it work adding "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" when calling java; I had to modify ob-ditaa.el for this.

Probably a patch is needed for org-mode if this is the solution. Or some java-guru could comment on how to set this property system-wide.

In the meantime, you can search for ob-ditaa.el, and edit the following line:

```
(cmd (concat "java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar "
```

Then re-evaluate this function by pressing M-C-x with the point somewhere in the function definition.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how long it takes to re-evaluate the function? I did what you say but now I only get ascii output. I'll add the output of my export to the main question.

Comment: Re-evaluating the function takes no time; you should see "org-babel-execute:ditaa" notification in the minibuffer meaning that the function has been re-evaluated and ready for use. Note that you may need to byte-compile this file, etc. if you want this change permanent for new emacs sessions.

Comment: Maybe the messages buffer helps error finding. Press 'F1 e' to see messages.

Comment: I added the error messages to the main post and there doesn't seem to be an error. If I want to byte compile I suppose I need to run the make file. I'll try that and let you know!

Comment: I ran he make file, still same results.

Comment: I managed to fix it. My problem with the #+begin_src not working was because I didn't specify ditaa as a language in my .emacs file. Thank you for the help. I'm so satisfied that this works now...

Comment: Great! I'll post a patch and request for comments to the mailing list.

Comment: Official solution already in development version of org-mode; see thread at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/41184/focus=41196 Should now work out of the box without any reference to encoding